# What's the maximum number of elements or file size for an HTML document?

Tags: html

I am working with an HTML file which has >71K dom elements and is around 2.3Mb in size.

Now, whilst I fully appreciate why this is so slow, can anyone provide examples/research regarding the maximum number of elements and or file size a single HTML document can reasonably be, which might help me state my case?

Thanks

Edit - I appreciate there is no definitive limit, I am looking for examples/evidence from respected sources to show that this file is silly big.

Comment: I guess this depends on the browser. But 71k elements is really far beyond reasonable

Comment: I'm not sure that there *is* a maximum defined size of an html file, although I suspect that the maximum, in practice, is defined by how long your users are prepared to wait for the page to load. Have you considered breaking this page down into smaller, more manageable, units? With ajax, lazy-loading or such? 71k elements is huge, and unwieldy (I'd have thoguht...).

Comment: There is no maximum file size, that depends on the computing power (primarily RAM) on the client-PC.

Comment: try it with an older IE, you have very good chances to crash it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have any research or a definite answer for you, but I think you will have trouble finding those.  The main problem is that "reasonable" is a subjective thing.  Also, a document that renders at a "reasonable" speed for you in one browser, may be much slower in another (thnk about the speed differences between just the major browsers like IE, firefox, chrome, and safari).

You also have to consider how fast the network connection is for the users trying to download your html document.  Sure most people have fast enough internet now that a couple MB file isn't a big, but not everyone does, and even for those with quick internet what if your html starts getting up to a couple hundred MB or a GB+?

There are tons of variables that will affect how slow your HTML document loads/renders, and I think in the end the only way to guage reasonable is what your users are willing to put up with.  Just my 2cents.